# Joins in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have two files :

1.Edge list file( vertex_id, vertex_id )
        This file contains one line for each edge in the graph with source & sink vertex id.

2.Partition file(vertex id , partition id  )
     This file contains one line for each vertex. Each line has two values first number is  and second number is

I want following output :

vertex_id  partition_id, vertex_id  partition_id

i.e. each vertex id in the edge file should be concatenated with its partition id.

Is there any possible solution to achieve this in a single map-reduce job?

Answer (score 0):

Joining is a very common pattern in MapReduce.

- Check the [Data-Intensive Text Processing with MapReduce](http://lintool.github.io/MapReduceAlgorithms/) on the different ways of joining.
- Check the [MapReduce Design Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025122.do) for the joins. The corresponding join code is [here](https://github.com/adamjshook/mapreducepatterns/tree/master/MRDP/src/main/java/mrdp/ch5).

FYI, it's a matter of a couple of lines of code with [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/) to do a join using [RDD.join()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.join).